# What can be done to minimize the risk if 90% organic traffic comes to just one blog page?

Tags: seo, google

I have a technology blog and now it has around 25,000 organic traffic per month.

It has around 300 blog posts.

But almost 90% of 25,000 organic traffic comes to just one post. That traffic is almost stable since around two years.

But I have a fear that what happen if that pages goes down in search result. It can lost almost all revenue because my blog is live because of that post.

What can I do in this type of situation? I mean why Google gives good traffic for just 1 post out of 300 posts. Or is it normal?